# foreach loop from array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have some question about `foreach array`.

If I have some data: `"'a1','a2'","'b1','b2'","'c1','c2'"` And I tired to get `a1,b1,c1`.

When I tested the code below,

```
$aa = array("'a1','a2'","'b1','b2'","'c1','c2'");
foreach($aa as $bb){
    $cc = array($bb);//var_dump($cc);  (1) { [0]=> string(9) "'a1','a2'" }...
    foreach($cc as $dd){
        echo $dd.'<br />';
        break;
    }
}
```

It will output:

```
'a1','a2'
'b1','b2'
'c1','c2'
```

Wrong with `$cc = array($bb)`... What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You realize that you only have 3 strings, right?

Comment: You store a string in an array and then echo the only element (the string) in that array=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one level array, not two. Elements are just strings for php, not arrays. That's why your code doesn't work.

Replace your `$cc = array($bb)` string with smth like this:

```
$cc = explode(',', $bb);
foreach($cc as $dd){
    echo trim($dd, "'").'<br />';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Right! In context, the value `'a1','a2'` could be further split into an array and so exploding it made the `a1`, `b1`, `c1` easily accessible :)